# SwiftUI move List items between list Sections

Tags: list, swiftui, insert, drag, sections

In the code bellow I am trying to achieve the moving (dragging) from a list sections to another list section.

I have an enum which contains 5 elements and a state var (activeElements) that contains an array of those enum.
In a view there is a list with 2 sections:

- first section contains elements that are selected from the section 2 (let's call them active elements)
- the second section contains elements from the enum which are not contained in selected array

In section 1 I should be able to move elements around and also to drag an element to section2 at a desired position.
In section 2 I should be able to drag elements to section 1 and I don't care about the moving elements inside this section.

The section1 works perfect. My problem is that I cannot drag from section2 to section1. I can only drag from section 2 to section 2 (the plus green dot appears only there).
If I add onMove to the section 2 I lose the dragging from section 1 to section 2. The sections will move elements only inside them.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve moving from a section to another? Or maybe how I can move elements between 2 foreach in the same section.

Here is the code:

```
enum RandomElements: Int, CaseIterable {
    case element1 = 1
    case element2 = 2
    case element3 = 3
    case element4 = 4
    case element5 = 5
}

extension RandomElements {
    var string: String {
        switch self {
        case .element1:
            return "element1"
        case .element2:
            return "element2"
        case .element3:
            return "element3"
        case .element4:
            return "element4"
        case .element5:
            return "element5"
        }
    }
}

struct TwoSections: View {
    @State var activeElements: [RandomElements] = []
    @State var listMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Active elements")) {
                ForEach(activeElements, id: \.self) { elem in
                    HStack {
                        Text(elem.string)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                            .onTapGesture { activeElements.remove(at: activeElements.firstIndex(of: elem)!) }
                    }
                    .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: String(elem.rawValue) as NSString ) }
                }
                .onInsert(of: [.plainText], perform: dropToSection1)
                .onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                    activeElements.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
                }
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Available elements")) {
                ForEach(RandomElements.allCases, id: \.self) { elem in
                    if !activeElements.contains(elem) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(elem.string)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .onTapGesture { activeElements.append(elem) }
                        }
                        .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: String(elem.rawValue) as NSString ) }
                    }
                }
                .onInsert(of: [.plainText], perform: dropToSection2)
                //                .onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                //                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            EditButton()
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
    }
    
    private func dropToSection1(at index: Int, _ items: [NSItemProvider]) {
        for item in items {
            _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { droppedString, _ in
                if let statusType = Int(droppedString ?? "") {
                    activeElements.remove(at: activeElements.firstIndex(of: RandomElements(rawValue: statusType)!)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func dropToSection2(at index: Int, _ items: [NSItemProvider]) {
        for item in items {
            _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { droppedString, _ in
                if let statusType = Int(droppedString ?? "") {
                    print("append \(RandomElements(rawValue: statusType)!)")
                    activeElements.insert(RandomElements(rawValue: statusType)!, at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The onMove between sections is not supported so far.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to only use ONE ForEach. You can't move items between different "ForEach" blocks.

This works for me:

```
List {    
  ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
    Section {
        Text(String(i))
    } header: {
        if(i==0) {
            Text("First Header")
        }
        if(i==5) {
            Text("Second Header")
        }
    }
    
  }
  .onMove(perform: move)
  .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
```

Return nothing from from header block to group your items.