# How to drag and drop to rearrange sections and items in DisclosureGroup in a List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `List` that is comprised of `Sections` where each section contains a `DisclosureGroup` to hide and show individual items in that section. I'd like to add the ability to drag and drop on the DisclosureGroup label cell to reorder sections in the list. Additionally, I'd like the ability to drag and drop to rearrange the order of items within each DisclosureGroup.

I've tried used the `onDrag` and `onDrop` modifiers to rearrange sections, but the functions in my `DropViewDelegate` are never called because I'm using the modifier inside of a List.

```
struct DropViewDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let destinationItem: ItemSet
    @Binding var sets: [ItemSet]
    @Binding var draggedItem: ItemSet?
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        draggedItem = nil
        return true
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if let draggedItem {
            let fromIndex = sets.firstIndex(of: draggedItem)
            if let fromIndex {
                let toIndex = sets.firstIndex(of: destinationItem)
                if let toIndex, fromIndex != toIndex {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.sets.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: fromIndex), toOffset: (toIndex > fromIndex ? (toIndex + 1) : toIndex))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ItemSet: ObservableObject, Equatable, Identifiable {
    static func == (lhs: ItemSet, rhs: ItemSet) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var items: [String]
    
    init(name: String, items: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sets: [ItemSet] = [
        ItemSet(name: "Set 1", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 2", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 3", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 4", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"])
    ]
    @State var draggedSet: ItemSet? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sets) { set in
                Section(header: Text(set.name).font(Font.headline).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.label))) {
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        ForEach(set.items, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text(set.name)
                    }
                }
                .textCase(nil)
                .tint(.primary)
                .onDrag {
                    draggedSet = set
                    return NSItemProvider(object: set.name as NSString)
                }
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropViewDelegate(destinationItem: set, sets: $sets, draggedItem: $draggedSet))
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .listSectionSpacing(.compact)
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the `onMove` modifier, but that function is not getting called either with I release the DisclosureGroup label cell from a drag operation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sets: [ItemSet] = [
        ItemSet(name: "Set 1", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 2", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 3", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 4", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"])
    ]
    @State var draggedSet: ItemSet? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sets) { set in
                Section(header: Text(set.name).font(Font.headline).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.label))) {
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        ForEach(set.items, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text(set.name)
                    }
                }
                .textCase(nil)
                .tint(.primary)
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .listSectionSpacing(.compact)
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        sets.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve my desired drag and drop functionality using SwiftUI without changing my view to not using a List or DisclosureGroup?

Comment: I don't think you need `DropViewDelegate` to move rows in `List`.  Besides, you should do it in a different `View` with the whole list with it.

Answer (score 1):

List sections cannot be reordered, and list rows cannot be reordered across sections. ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72190241/5133585))

You'd need to put everything that can be reordered into the same section,

```
List {
    ForEach($sets) { $set in
        // this is simulating the section header
        Text(set.name).font(Font.headline).fontWeight(.bold)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .moveDisabled(true)
        
        DisclosureGroup {
            ForEach(set.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onMove(perform: { from, to in
                set.items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
            })
        } label: {
            Text(set.name)
        }
        .textCase(nil)
        .tint(.primary)
    }.onMove { from, to in
        sets.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
    }
}
```

Note that `ItemSet` should be a struct:

```
struct ItemSet: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var items: [String]
    
    init(name: String, items: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve drag and drop functionality within both the sections and items of your List, you need to use onDrag and onDrop modifiers at both levels: for the sections and for the individual items within each section.

Here's how you can modify your ContentView to enable drag and drop for both sections and items:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sets: [ItemSet] = [
        ItemSet(name: "Set 1", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 2", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 3", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]),
        ItemSet(name: "Set 4", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"])
    ]
    @State var draggedSet: ItemSet? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Section(header: Text(sets[index].name).font(Font.headline).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.label))) {
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        ForEach(sets[index].items.indices, id: \.self) { itemIndex in
                            Text(sets[index].items[itemIndex])
                                .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: String(itemIndex) as NSString) }
                                .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropViewDelegate(destinationItem: sets[index], sets: $sets, draggedItem: $draggedSet, sourceIndexPath: IndexPath(row: itemIndex, section: index)))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text(sets[index].name)
                            .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: String(index) as NSString) }
                            .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DropViewDelegate(destinationItem: sets[index], sets: $sets, draggedItem: $draggedSet, sourceIndexPath: IndexPath(row: -1, section: index)))
                    }
                }
                .textCase(nil)
                .tint(.primary)
                .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                    sets.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        .listSectionSpacing(.compact)
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
}
```

With this setup, you're enabling drag and drop at both the section and item levels. Each Text view representing an item is given its own onDrag and onDrop modifiers to handle individual item reordering. The onMove modifier is used at the section level to enable reordering of sections.

Also, ensure that your DropViewDelegate handles both section and item reordering appropriately. Make sure to pass the correct source index path based on whether it's an item or a section being dragged.

This approach should allow you to achieve the desired drag and drop functionality within your List while still using DisclosureGroup and without removing the List.